# Alt+Tab not working after swapping Control key with Alt key with setxkbmap

Tags: debian, keyboard-shortcuts, mate-desktop

I'm on Debian 9.11 with the MATE desktop (pinebook pro) and I have a custom keyboard mapping that makes Caps Lock a control key and swap Left Control key with Left Alt.
The commands are as follow:

```bsh
setxkbmap -option ctrl:nocaps
setxkbmap -option ctrl:swap_lalt_lctl
```

However after I execute that, the new `Alt` key (key written `Ctrl` on it) doesn't work as expected.

When I perform an `Alt+Tab` I'm expecting to have the small popup appearing to let me choose which window I'd like to switch to. But instead, this small popup seems to not be aware anymore of the opened programs and as a result I can't switch back to any program I want.

Is there a way to fix this? 
Note that I've tried to setup this custom mapping with `xmodmap` but I failed. 
`setxkbmap` seems much easier in my case but this faulty behavior is annoying...

Comment: Use `xev` to find out which (raw) keycode is mapped to which char / function.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following command after your setxkbmap for example:

```
setxkbmap -layout us -variant intl
```

then

```
/usr/bin/setxkbmap
```

[Found the answer here](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1324163)